# Test VueJs localization using Nightwatch

Tags: vue.js, localization, internationalization, nightwatch.js, vue-i18n

I have an application that I started in English from scratch. I had nightwatch tests and everything is working perfectly fine... but after adding 2 more languages, I want the main tests to run as they used to in English, then change the browser language (since that's the criteria on which I choose the language) so I can run the other tests in German or French... etc. Is there a way to start a test suite by changing the browser's language?

I looked into the documentation and found nothing in this area

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the language and run the tests locally, I did the following:

```
chrome: {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    chromeOptions: {
      prefs: {
        intl: { accept_languages: "ss-ZA" }
      }, args: []
    }
  }
}
```

this allows you to run the tests locally, on only that language. or you can manage setting that locale code to a variable in a way and try setting it at the beginning of your test suite.

I did not get that far, because in my case, I have to run my tests headless because they will run later on a remote git server that runs only headless tests. According to [this issue](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/900) on Nightwatch's github page, setting a browser language parameter for a headless test is not possible!